# ng-option or ng-repeat cannot updated after change array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i used ng-option or ng-repeat and change value of array but not bind new values

```
<select multiple="true" ng-model="staticField.text">
    <option ng-repeat="t in Activitydata track by $index ">{{t}}</option>
</select>
```

and i change it to ng-option and does work

that's angular js code

```
$scope.Activitydata = [];
$scope.ActivityFound = function (from) {
    for (var h = 0; h < allRequestDetails.procurationCustomers.length; h++) {
        activitynote = allRequestDetails.procurationCustomers[h].notes;
        actList = activitynote.split('|');
        for (i = 0; i < actList.length; i++) {
            //alert(1);
            console.log('element : ' + actList[i]);
            $scope.Activitydata.push(actList[i]);
        }
        $scope.Activitydata.removeDuplicates();
        $scope.Activitydata.unique();
        $scope.Activitydata.remove("");
    };
    ....
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ng-repeat the you should provide what value to bind as..

```
<select multiple="true" ng-model="staticField.text">
<option ng-repeat="t in Activitydata track by $index" value={{t}}>{{t}}</option>
```

So in this case the value of t gets bind to the ng-model..If you are using ng-options then you should use as..

```
<select multiple="true" ng-model="staticField.text" ng-options="t.code as t.name for t in Activitydata track by $index ">
<option value="">Select</option>
```

I am assuming here that ActivityData contains **name** and **code** as property....